# Add noise to parameters of ensemble in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I use the following code to create parameters for an ensemble of models stored as list of lists holding tuples of weights and biases. How do I efficiently add random noise to all parameters of the ensemble with JAX? I tried to use `tree_map()` but run into many errors probably caused by the nested structure.

Could you please provide guidance on how to use `tree_map()` in this case or point to other methods that JAX provides for such a case?

```
from jax import Array
from jax import random

def layer_params(dim_in: int, dim_out: int, key: Array) -> tuple[Array]:
    w_key, b_key = random.split(key=key)
    weights = 0 * random.normal(key=w_key, shape=(dim_out, dim_in))
    biases = 0 * random.normal(key=w_key, shape=(dim_out,))
    return weights, biases

def init_params(layer_dims: list[int], key: Array) -> list[tuple[Array]]:
    keys = random.split(key=key, num=len(layer_dims))
    params = []
    for dim_in, dim_out, key in zip(layer_dims[:-1], layer_dims[1:], keys):
        params.append(layer_params(dim_in=dim_in, dim_out=dim_out, key=key))
    return params

def init_ensemble(key: Array, num_models: int, layer_dims: list[int]) -> list:
    keys = random.split(key=key, num=num_models)
    models = [init_params(layer_dims=layer_dims, key=key) for key in keys]
    return models

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_models = 2
    layer_dims = [2, 3, 4]
    
    key = random.PRNGKey(seed=1)
    key, subkey = random.split(key)
    ensemble = init_ensemble(key=subkey, num_models=num_models, layer_dims=layer_dims)

    # Add noise to ensemble.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this:

```py
from jax import tree_util
leaves, tree = tree_util.tree_flatten(ensemble)
key, *subkeys = random.split(key, len(leaves) + 1)
subkeys = tree_util.tree_unflatten(tree, subkeys)

def add_noise(val, key, eps=0.1):
  return val + eps * random.normal(key, val.shape)

ensemble_with_noise = tree_util.tree_map(add_noise, ensemble, subkeys)
```

Essentially, you create a tree of subkeys with the same structure as the tree of parameters, then use `tree_map` to apply the noise function to the tree.